# Black Screen when loading rss news

Tags: android

Im trying to load some rss news getting from a blogspot.The Rss is a little different.This is its form

```
<feed>
<entry>

<id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-7518961852167560062.post-4523318015704090243</id>
<published>2011-07-07T15:08:00.003+03:00</published>
<updated>2011-07-07T15:11:04.213+03:00</updated>
<category scheme='http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#' term='Karaoke Night'/>
<category scheme='http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#' term='Deutsche Ecke'/>
<category scheme='http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#' term='Johnny Vavouras'/>
<category scheme='http://www.blogger.com/atom/ns#' term='BOIKOS SA'/>
<title type='text'>Karaoke Night</title>
<summary type='text'>Be The Star Part 2 Την πρώτη φορά έγινε χαμός! Όλες και όλοι θέλατε να πιείτε την μπύρα σας και να πείτε και ένα τραγουδάκι. Το ένα έγιναν δύο, τα δύο τρία και τα τρία τέσσερα κοκ. Και όταν παίρνω φόρα τίποτα δεν με σταματά ήσασταν! Και αφού περάσαμε καλά και ρωτήσατε πότε θα ξαναγίνει βραδιά Karaoke, ορίστε η απάντηση:Ο Johnny Vavouras και η Μαρία Γκαγκώση θα είναι πάλι κοντά μας με τεράστια </summary>
<link rel='replies' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://deutscheecke-gr.blogspot.com/feeds/4523318015704090243/comments/default' title='Σχόλια ανάρτησης'/>
<link rel='replies' type='text/html' href='http://deutscheecke-gr.blogspot.com/2011/07/karaoke-night.html#comment-form' title='0 σχόλια'/>
<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/7518961852167560062/posts/default/4523318015704090243'/>
<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/7518961852167560062/posts/default/4523318015704090243'/>
<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://deutscheecke-gr.blogspot.com/2011/07/karaoke-night.html' title='Karaoke Night'/>
<author>
<name>ranic19</name>
<uri>http://www.blogger.com/profile/18311687460079471825</uri>
<email>ranic19@gmail.com</email>
<gd:extendedProperty xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' name='OpenSocialUserId' value='04547458941145961505'/>
</author>
<media:thumbnail xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' url='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-A0grH2ckHtA/ThLlFH1vUdI/AAAAAAAAAPw/uuo4hhJDygo/s72-c/DEUTSCHE+ECKE+14-7.jpg' height='72' width='72'/>
<thr:total>0</thr:total>

</entry>

</feed>
```

So i m trying to change the usual way i m getting rss....my new baseFeedParser class is this:

```
static String feedUrlString = "http://deutscheecke-gr.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default";


    static final String ATOM_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
    static final String FEED = "feed";
    static final String ENTRY = "entry";

    static final String PUBLISHED = "publised";
    static final String SUMMARY = "summary";
    static final String LINK = "link";
    static final String HREF = "href";

    static final String TITLE = "title";

    private final URL feedUrl;

    protected BaseFeedParser(){
        try {
            this.feedUrl = new URL(feedUrlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected InputStream getInputStream() {
        try {
            return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public List<Message> parse() {
        final Message currentMessage = new Message();
        RootElement root = new RootElement(ATOM_NAMESPACE,FEED);
        final List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        Element item= root.getChild(ENTRY);


        item.getChild(PUBLISHED).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setDate(body);
            }
        });
        item.getChild(SUMMARY).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setDescription(body);
            }
        });

    //  Element itemlist2 = root.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE,LINK);
    //  Element item2 = itemlist2.getChild(ATOM_NAMESPACE,HREF);
    //  item2.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener(){
    //      public void end() {
    //          messages.add(currentMessage.copy());
    //      }
    //  });
        item.getChild(LINK).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setLink(HREF);
            }
        });
        item.getChild(TITLE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener(){
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setTitle(body);
            }
        });
        try {
            Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Now,in my main class i m trying to load the title of the rss like that

```
public class events extends ListActivity {

    private List<Message> messages;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.events);
        loadFeed();
    }

    private void loadFeed(){
        try{
            BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
            messages = parser.parse();
            List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
            for (Message msg : messages){

                titles.add(msg.getTitle());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowevents,titles);
            this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("Deutsche Ecke News",t.getMessage(),t);
        }
    }
```

FINALLY,when i m running my app i have no erros but the only think i see is a black screen...so i think that my error is in my code...may i have some help please?is someting wrong here?thanks!!:)

Answer (score 0):

Your loadFeed method is running on the main UI thread, so it is blocking the UI from updating.  Try running loadFeed on a separate thread.  You might want to look into using AsyncTask or a Handler for that purpose.

Comment: i have used asyncTask in my first "main" class where is the button of the rss.With async task i present a progress bar until the news load.You think that i must go my loadFeed there?

Comment: could i have a black screen because its not loading any news?

Comment: This part of loadFeed needs to done in the doInBackground of your AsyncTask:
 BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
            messages = parser.parse();
            List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
            for (Message msg : messages){

                titles.add(msg.getTitle());
            }